# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl' when I try to deploy my django project on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I try to deploy my django project on heroku, and follow commands below

```
heroku login
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
heroku create
heroku git:remote -a name
pip install gunicorn
gunicorn application.wsgi
```

when it comes to the latest command, error occurs:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Is the underlying operating system Windows? fcntl is not available on Windows system and Gunicorn does not work on windows

Run a WSGI web app (like Django) on Windows uing [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/)

Basically all you have to do is replace the gunicorn call with:

```
waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 myapp.wsgi:application
```

For typical apps this will give you the same result as running gunicorn. :) Good luck!

Comment: I see. I using windows 10. But what is alternative for solving this?

Comment: you may switch from Gunicorn to Waitress which is a very good alternative.. updating my answer with the steps

Comment: Sorry, I still a beginner, I don't know about Gunicorn and Waitress. Can you recommend some guidelines or resources of deploying django to heroku for beginner?

Comment: please check the link in the answer that I have provided.. you may follow the guidelines in the mentioned link

Answer (score 0):

The fcntl module is not available on Windows. you should use waitress for http and for https use django-sslserver.